# QtHelpFramework: как использовать для мультиязычного приложения?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, multilanguage

Делаю своего хелп ассистента, основанного на QtHelpFramework. Ищу решение, которое позволит изменяя язык в приложении получать ссылки на документы того языка, который нужен. Есть ли у кого-то опыт в этой области? может ли кто-то подсказать, есть ли варианты предусмотренные варианты нативного использования или механизмы для использования?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть имеется тестовый код, закоментированный по правилам `Doxygen` для автогенерации документации:

```
/** \~english
 *    @mainpage Here you can place an ad
 *  \~
 *  \~russian 
 *   @mainpage Здесь вы можете разместить рекламу
 *  \~
 */
    
/** \~english
 *    @defgroup FOO FOO Module
 *    @brief Some module description
 *  \~
 *  \~russian 
 *   @defgroup FOO Модуль FOO
 *   @brief Какое-то описание модуля
 *  \~
 *  @{
 */

/** \~english
 *   @brief Main Foo interface 
 *  \~
 *  \~russian
 *   @brief Главный интерфейс Foo
 *  \~
*/
class IFoo
{
public:
    /** 
     * \~english
     *  @brief Make foo
     *  @param[in] bar Bar value
     *  @return true if bar is true; otherwise returns false
     * \~
     * \~russian 
     *  @brief выполнить foo
     *  @param[in] bar Значение bar
     *  @return true если bar истинно; иначе false
     * \~
     */
    virtual bool makeFoo(int bar) = 0;
};

/**
 *  @} 
 */
```

Как видно, документация представлена для русского и английского языков.

Далее запустить `doxywizard` и создать новый проект для документации, указав путь до файла выше. Во вкладке `Expert` выбрать `Project` и справа найти параметр `OUTPUT_LANGUAGE`, который выставить `English`.

Ниже выбрать `HTML` и отметить параметр `GENERATE_QHP` галочкой, параметру `QHG_LOCATION` указать абсолютный путь до программы `qhelpgenerator` для генерации сжатых файлов документации `Qt` (у меня `/usr/bin/qhelpgenerator`), параметру `QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER` указать название виртуальной папки без слешей (например `doc`) и в параметре `QHP_NAMESPACE` указать пространство имён с двумя первыми буквами языка (например `en.foomaker.1.0`):

```
# Записи в файле проекта документации Doxygen
GENERATE_QHP       = yes
QHP_NAMESPACE      = "en.foomaker.1.0"
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER = "doc"
QHG_LOCATION       = "/usr/bin/qhelpgenerator"
```

Во вкладке `Run` запустить генерацию документации кнопкой `Run doxygen`. В директории проекта появится папка `qch` c файлом документации. Переименуйте его в `en.qch`.

Теперь выставите параметр `OUTPUT_LANGUAGE` в `Russian`, а `QHP_NAMESPACE`      в "ru.foomaker.1.0", и снова сгенерируйте документацию, уже на русском языке. Файл из папки `qch` переименовать в `ru.qch`.

Итого получили файлы со сжатой документацией `en.qch` и `ru.qch` на английской и русском языках соответственно.

Теперь создадим файл проекта для коллекции сжатых файлов документации `collection.qhcp`, в котором указать отксительные пути к вышеуказанным файлам:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<QHelpCollectionProject version="1.0">
    <docFiles>
        <register>
            <file>qch/en.qch</file>
            <file>qch/ru.qch</file>
        </register>
    </docFiles>
</QHelpCollectionProject>
```

Теперь сгенерировать файл `collection.qhc`, который будет понимать движок `Qt Help Framework`:

```
qhelpgenerator collection.qhcp -o qhc/collection.qhc
```

Полученные файлы `qch/en.qch`, `qch/en.qch` и `qhc/collection.qhc` это по сути базы данных `SQLite`, которые должны поставляться вместе с программой как отдельные файлы, т.к. механизм ресурсов `Qt` их не поддерживает.

Для отображения доки создать класс `HelpBrowser`, наследуемый от `QTextBrowser` (т.к. он может отображать ссылки со схемой документации `Qt` `qthelp://`), и переопределить ему член-функцию:

```
QVariant HelpBrowser::loadResource(int type, const QUrl &url)
{
    if (url.scheme() == "qthelp")
        return QVariant(m_helpEngine->fileData(url));
    else
        return QTextBrowser::loadResource(type, url);
}
```

Ну и в окошке приложения создать комбобокс со значениями `ru` и `en`, и выполнить код по типу такого:

```
// Системный язык (ru, en, ...)
const QString lang { QLocale::system().name().left(2) };
// Создаём движок с файлом коллекции
QHelpEngine* engine = new QHelpEngine(QString{"/path/to/qhc/collection.qhc"}, this);
engine->setupData();
// По умолчанию все файлы документации из коллекции зарегистрированы, поэтому я их сперва un'регистрирую :)
QStringList files{};
for(const auto& namSpace : engine->registeredDocumentations()) {
    files << engine->documentationFileName(namSpace);
    engine->unregisterDocumentation(namSpace);
}
// и регистрирую доку в соответствии с текущей локалью
engine->registerDocumentation( QString{"/path/to/qch/%1.qch"}.arg(lang) );
engine->contentWidget()->setWindowTitle("Content widget");
engine->contentWidget()->show();

// Создаём браузер доки, и выставляем доку в соответствии с текущей локалью
HelpBrowser* browser = new HelpBrowser(engine);
browser->setWindowTitle("Browser");
browser->resize(800,600);
browser->setSource(QUrl(QString{"qthelp://%1.foomaker.1.0/doc/index.html"}.arg(lang)));
connect(engine->contentWidget(), &QHelpContentWidget::linkActivated, browser, qOverload<const QUrl&>(&HelpBrowser::setSource));
browser->show();

connect(ui->comboBox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, 
[engine](const QString& lang) {
    QStringList files{};
    for(const auto& namSpace : engine->registeredDocumentations()) {
        files << engine->documentationFileName(namSpace);
        engine->unregisterDocumentation(namSpace);
    }
    engine->registerDocumentation( QString{"/path/to/qch/%1.qch"}.arg(lang) );
    engine->setupData();
});

ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(ui->comboBox->findText(lang));
```